# Shock cones coming off a non-ablative object at various velocities

Tags: atmospheric-science

This may be the wrong stackexchange for this, apologies if it is.

Lets say we have a sphere 1 meter in diameter that weighs 4.5 short tons. It will not change states or shape from its solid spherical form regardless of the heat/pressure/etc it experiences at these velocities. It accelerates from 0 to the mach number listed below in a single planck length of movement. What kind of shock waves will it be creating when traveling through normal sea level atmosphere at the velocities listed below.

Mach 32.6

Mach 163

Mach 350

Comment: No-ones ever gone that fast.
Why 32.6 not 30?

Comment: @JMLCarter 36.2 mach is earth's escape velocity, 136 mach was the velocity of the 2000 lb cover plate from the Plumbbob nuclear test pascal-b, and mach 350 is roughly lightning stepped leader velocity. As to no one going that fast, yeah I could find like no literature documenting tests of objects beyond like 20 km/s, and that was only quick articles about tests done at Sandia National laboratories. But that small documentation wasn't even discussion the atmospheric effects of such velocity, instead it was research for micro meteorite cratering, so it may have been done in a vacuum.

Comment: You don't need to go at escape velocity to get to orbit, only about mach 24. Once in orbit, obviously, no one can eat ice cream.

Comment: @JMLCarter I'm not concerned with reaching orbit, I'm curious how the atmosphere at sea level would react to my theoretical object that those velocities.

Comment: It will create circularly symmetric sonic shock waves of higher energy at higher speed... ?

Comment: At those kinda velocities, shouldn't the shockwave become plasma?

Comment: When the shockwave energy density exceeds that to ionise air, then yes, it must do. And as it cools it wil form air again mostly. Does that mean it's a different kind of shockwave?

Answer (score 0):

You will see no effect and likely hit no air molecules during the acceleration.

Comment: What about as it's traveling after acceleration. That's really what I was actually curious about, sorry if the initial questions was unclear.